Flyback converter primary inductor current oscillation
I am designing a switch mode power supply to go from 12 to 220V. The. topology is a flyback converter with a 1:10 ratio, working in DCM. I have based my design on the high voltage typical application that can be found on the LT3757A controller data sheet, pg32. This is the same controller I am using for my design.
By now, I have only simulated my design. Everything seems to work fine, except for when I try to introduce the effect of the interwinding capacitance on my design. I have obtained its value from the transformer data sheet DA2033, and I am modelling it as a capacitor between the inductor terminals as it can be seen in the attached schematic (C9). Obviously, I know this is not a real/perfect model of this capacitance, but I think it should be fine as a first approach.

On top you can see the primary inductor current I have when I do not model the interwinding capacitance. I understand where these oscillations come from. Despite that, with the interwinding capacitance, I obtain the waveform on bottom.

I have added the square wave at NOMS' gate for clarification since I can not align both simulations.
It might be difficult to appreciate, but we still have the current ramp with a huge oscillation overlapped.The design is still working even with this inductor current but I have the following doubts.

I want to know why is this happening. Where does this oscillation come from? My guess is that Cwinding and Llkg are resonating.
Should I be worried about this before building my power supply? Maybe I am seeing these waveforms because I have use a very simple model of the interwinding capacitance.


Have you modeled the DC resistance of the coils? Have you used a fast diode for the output rectifier? Can you please use the same time base scales on both graphs and properly align them?

Your interwinding capacitance does not appear straight across primary plus to secondary “phase” but rather as from all over your primary winding to all over your secondary. If you have plenty of layers, perhaps more from start or end of one winding to start or end of the other. Try to split it up to four capacitors, two straight across from top and bottom and two in a cross pattern would be a bit closer to reality. What’s your transformer build up?

@Andyaka No, I have not added series resistance and the diode is an ideal spice model. I have updated my question with you suggestions in order make it clearer.

What is i(L3) and what is v(n016)?

@winny Trying what you suggest slightly decreases the oscillation, but I don't know if the real case (having the capacitance completely distributed through the windings) will be good enough for not to worry about this during simulation.

As you have noticed, it won't make the oscillation go away, just make it a bit closer to reality. 76 pF isn't huge, but you could make it smaller if needed with a custom transformer. Unfortunately, your oscillation frequency is rather close to your current ramp signal so a simple low-pass filter may not attenuate your oscillation much before you steal away your actual wanted signal.

@Andyaka I have updated the waveform. Maybe is clearer now.

What is the frequency of the ringing and, have you tried to see if numerically it equals the resonant point of the added capacitor and the leakage inductance?

I would first add a realistic diode model - the D you have is the default model - and I would change the integration to gear in the settings menu. Finally, I try to stay away from coupled inductors: I prefer to resort to a perfect dc transformer to which I add a primary inductance, a leakage term and a turns ratio.

@Andyaka Theoretical resonance frequency of Cinterwinding and Llkg do not match. They would theoretically resonate at 47MHz, but the ringing I see is 3.3MHz. Despite that, it disappears whenever I delete any of them, so I would say both (Cwind and LLp) are involved in this ringing.

@VerbalKint Do you mean to use two perfectly coupled inductors and add extra inductors to model leakage? As far as I know, transformers are modelled with coupled inductors in spice, so I am not sure to understand your suggestion. Moreover, what is the main benefit of doing so?

You would use a dc transformer characterized by $N$ its turns ratio, then add a primary inductance and a separate leakage inductance. These terms are then easily individually adjustable (and readable) whereas you need to extract them from a coupling coefficient. Besides, I believe there is more burden on the engine with a coupling coefficient than with the discrete transformer. I've always used that model for years, single- or multi-winding configuration. I don't say this is the source in your case but worth giving it a try.

The transformer datasheet is not very clear on this parameter:

I would understand the plain meaning of this note as, "short all other pins together, then measure between the indicated pins".  That measurement will almost certainly be inductive (somewhat below the leakage spec).
A typical capacitance measurement would short all primary and all secondary pins together, respectively, then measure the capacitance of the isolation barrier as the resulting two-terminal component, at such frequency where parasitics of the windings do not apply (probably 100kHz is fine here).
It is likely this is what they meant, but singling out pins 1 and 3, and leaving "all other pins" so ambiguous, has disastrous results.
In general, we can model a transformer to the 2nd order, as one having lumped inductances and capacitances around/between terminals:
 
From: own website, https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/XfmrEquiv.png
Exact placement of Ciso1/2 connections around LLp and LLs, and whether we reflect LLp/LLs on both sides (left or right, or top or bottom), or use a single lumped equivalent (one LL into an ideal transformer), varies with model fitment, winding design.  (Note also that T1 will be an nonideal transformer having k=1, finite magnetizing inductance, and core loss.)
Modeling to higher frequencies, we need a higher order model, and more LC elements -- and have more options of how to connect them, so modeling as well as measuring becomes more difficult.  In general, there will be some transmission notch, where LL and Ciso resonate, and peak where LL and Cp or Cs resonate, then asymptotic attenuation above that frequency; but where the asymptote actually starts, what slope it takes, and what other resonances appear along it, depend on construction (and indeed, a transformer can be constructed with fairly flat response above this cutoff, so it need not be a -40dB/dec asymptote as this model gives).
Whatever the case, resonances (and their asymptotes) are the result of physical construction: a transformer is a ball of wire, and where there is wire length*, there is inductance; and where there are wires in proximity to each other (whether of adjacent turns, or separate windings), there is capacitance.  Or more generally, where there are conductors in parallel, there are transmission lines, and thus characteristic impedance, and delay time (electrical length), from which we can obtain low-frequency equivalent inductance (leakage) and capacitance.
*Inductance is a property of space itself, and thus of any conductor that runs through it.  It is not specific to looping or spiraling conductors, but indeed any wire or trace has some.  This is a common oversight (by newbies; and omission, by their teachers!), but has real consequences, especially at the dI/dt seen in switching converters.  A typical 30V 2A 1MHz switching regulator IC needs mere millimeters maximum length for its critical switching loop (between switch(es) and bypass capacitor(s)).  You probably won't require quite such tight layout here, but beware that every mm matters.  (A ballpark figure for PCB traces is 0.5nH per mm of trace length.  This figure is lower when the traces are wide, and the distance between them (face to face) is shorter; trace over ground plane (broad coupled) is thus preferable to trace-beside-trace (edge coupled), etc.  And use a ground plane.)
Your choice is the worst possible case, putting the full lumped capacitance on the highest voltage switching node, to AC GND.  It is not likely that this is the actual case -- but it is also not inconsistent with the datasheet.
More likely, the capacitance is distributed along the windings, so manifests as maybe 1/4 as much between pairs of pins.  There will still be ringing, which can be dampened by connecting an R+C snubber in parallel with the rectifier diode.
You may wish to:

Contact the manufacturer for disambiguation (Coilcraft is generally quite responsive);
Choose a different, better specified part;
Order some samples and test them yourself (designing and measuring an impedance test jig would be an excellent exercise);
Research transformer analysis and design methods and wind one (or probably several) yourself, to better understand and optimize the system overall; or etc.


Should I be concerned this to pose a major problem for my design? It works simulation... Also, Why is it happening only during transistor on period?

Well, the values as shown are consuming significant switching energy, costing efficiency and stressing the diode much more.  I would not consider it a satisfactory design, and send the transformer back for redesign or selection. Whether it is a "major problem" for your purposes, I cannot know.  As for on-period, consider drawing an equivalent circuit with the transistor and supply shorted, and diode opened. What components remain, and what are their characteristics (resonant frequency and impedance in terms of values)?
